# Is there a one-line possibility to pass optional parameters without warning?

Tags: java, optional-parameters

I have the following method which takes optional arguments:

```
public void error(Message msg, Object... msgParams) {
        error(la.line, la.col, msg, msgParams);
        throw new Errors.PanicMode();
}
```

.. and I want to call it in a way like this:

```
private void handleCheck(boolean found, Message msg, Kind... expected) {
        if (!found) {
            error(msg, expected);
        }
}
```

**Problem:**

This gives me the following warning:

> Type Kind[] of the last argument to method error(Errors.Message,
>   Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to
>   Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual
>   arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.

It is still working without unexpected errors, but I'm curious if there is a way to call such a method without checking the parameter length or something like that, in one line.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you what to do in the warning message:

> Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation

So:

```
error(msg, (Object[]) expected);
```

Comment: thank you, based on this answer, and on some answers of the similar question I changed the method to "private void handleCheck(boolean found, Message msg, Object... expected)", which also works for this case